# AUTH, logging in and out of fat free framework and handling sessions and securing pages

Tags: php, session, authentication, fat-free-framework

The documentation doesn't talk much about logging in and out and handling security in general.In Symfony, you can secure pages of your site via a YML file. Does F3 have anything like that?

What is the recommended way to secure pages and handle a logged in user? I liked basic Auth, but it isn't very flexible, and it seems logging out is trickier. So I decided to set up a form for login/logout.

I would have assumed that Auth automatically creates a session, but from what I can tell it doesn't. So does that mean I need to manually do it?

Also, how do I block non authenticated visitors from the site? Do I need to add a SESSION check in each route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The freedom when using F3 is that you can/must implement this on your own.
You got multiple options here or can create some other creative solutions too, if your project requires it. The included Auth plugin doesn't create a SESSION of course, because it cannot know if you want to use a SESSION to track your users or maybe use other solutions (cookie, JWT, etc).

So in most cases you need to create an Auth controller where you check if a user is logged in or not - here you would probably use the Auth plugin and create the SESSION if you want that. From there on you got serveral other options.. just to name a few:

1. use a base controller, that your other controllers will extend (or a Trait) and add a beforeroute there, where you'll check if the user is logged in and allowed to access that ressource.
2. check the user rights in the front controller (index.php) and don't even register the routes that the user has no access to.
3. use a 3rd party plugin to add access checks to routes, i.e. [f3-access](https://github.com/xfra35/f3-access/)
4. use another [middleware router](https://github.com/ikkez/f3-middleware) to pre-flight the current request and add auth checks to multiple routes at once

Comment: Ok You're all I got so I guess this is it! RIGHT ANSWER!

Comment: How would I implement your option 2? It seems like the simplest, which is all I need right now. I used a basic if statement to check if ($f3).get('SESSION.pass') and wrapped that around my routes. Is that a good idea?

Comment: Your middleware solution looks good too, but for now I just needed to get it secured. I'll likely go back later and make it more robust.